# Trying to bufferedWrite to a txt file and it will not work

Tags: java, io, output, bufferedwriter

I am having trouble making the `bw.write(line)` call work. Here is my code:

```
    InputStreamReader fr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Yes.txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
        System.out.print(line);
        bw.write(line); //line causing the issue
    }

    bw.close();
        br.close();
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, but when i go into the Yes.txt file it's empty

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you need to call `.flush()` after you are done writing.  BufferedWriter is exactly what it sounds like: It writes to a buffer first and once that buffer is full it outputs what is contained within the buffer.  Calling `flush()` will flush out what is contained within the buffer.

Comment: Calling `close`causes the output to be flushed

Comment: @Reimeus Valid Point I forgot that